# how to transfer data from <a> tag to popup dialog in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

i dynamically generate this html code to delete an item with an id=3 for example:

```
"<a href='javascript:delete('" + item.id + "')>";
```

when i click this, it will execute delete('3');i change it as:

```
<a href='#delete' data-rel='popup' data-position-to='window' data-transition='pop'>
```

and add a  dialog for this  tag:

```
<div data-role='popup' id='delete'>
    <a href='javascript:delete(item.id)' data-role='button'>delete</a>
</div>
```

how to transfer the item's id to this popup dialog's  tag, any suggestion?

Comment: What do you want to transfer exactly? `$('#delete').append('<p>hello world</p>').popup('open');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like you might be going through the wrong way to achieve this. Some things to change :

1. [`delete` is a JavaScript keyword. You cant use it as a function.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)
2. Don't use the `onclick` attribute. It results in duplication. Instead, you could use a `click` event for repetitive actions.
3. You seem to have gotten the idea to create multiple popups (one for each `click` of the anchor tag). I think one would do.

Now, in correlation with whatever I've just put down, here's some sample code.

**HTML**

```
<a href='#' class='delete' data-num='" + i + "'>Delete me</a>
```

*(Note the `data-num` attribute in the HTML, the addition of `class` attribute and the removal of `onclick` in your code)*

**It could be replaced by JS which looks like this :**

```
$(this).on("click", ".delete", function (e) {
        //prevent default action
        e.preventDefault();
        //take the id value
        var id = $(this).data("num");
        //send that value to the popup
        $("#delete").find("span").html(id).end().popup("open");
});
```

A demo fiddle for you to look at : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/AxGde/2/